# Trouble binding an object with sub-objects

Tags: xamarin.forms.listview

I'm using Xamarin.Forms (C#) and am attempting an MVVM approach.

My classes:

```
public class Parent
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public Child Children { get; set; }

   public Parent GetOneParent() {...}
}

public class Child
{
   public string FavoriteFruit { get; set; }
}
```

First of all, what is this type of class called having a "compound" property (i.e. a collection of children)?  I don't know what this is referred to so I am limited in "Googling" it.

Ok, I create a single Parent object:

```
Parent OneParent = new Parent.GetOneParent();
```

Now I'd like to show in my XAML code:

1. parent name (in a label)
2. a list of children's favorite fruits (in a listview since there are multiple)

What's the binding syntax for a label and then a listview for this type of object?  {Binding ???}

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be rather simple... the binding context has to be specific to the page and then also more deeply, its controls.

So I did something like this...

1. In code-behind, I set the binding context:

   BindingContext = Parent;
2. Then in the XAML code...

> ```
> <StackLayout>
>     <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
> </StackLayout>
> <StackLayout>
>     <!-- Now specify a deeper within the Parent object -->
>     <ListView x:Name="ParticipantList"
>         ItemsSource="{Binding Participants}">
>
>         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
>             <DataTemplate>
>                 <TextCell Text="{Binding FavoriteFruit}" />
>             </DataTemplate>
>         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
>     </ListView>
> </StackLayout>
> ```

Hope that helps someone down the road!